# Two div at single line with 1 div at left side and another 1 at furthest right side

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a header with 1 div with title and subtitle will be on the top left and the img will be at the same line with title and subtitle but on the top right.

But now my img div will always be at the 2nd line and not in the same line.

I tried float to right side, display inline but doesnt work. Any advice thanks!

My code
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/popup.css">
    <link href="https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/7200c6dd8ac604abe09f5159e53a40c0?family=Mark+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>

    <div id="main-header-wrapper">
        <div id="main-header">
            <span id="main-header-1">Title</span> <span id="main-header-2">Subtitle</span>
        </div>

        <div id="icon_moreInfo">
            <img
                src="https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180718/brv/kisspng-computer-icons-icon-design-encapsulated-postscript-more-info-icon-5b4fcee4e70c74.9013090315319569649464.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

css

```
html {
    width: 279px;
    height: 127x;
   background: #EEEEEE;
}

#body {
    width:100%;
}

#main-header {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

#main-header-1 {
    font-family: 'Mark Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 450;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    color: #000000;
}

#main-header-2 {
    font-family: 'Mark Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 450;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    color: #5D5D5D;
}
.icon_moreInfo{
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  float:right;
 }

img{
  height:12px;
  width:12px;
}

.main-header-wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

codepen link:https://codepen.io/james263/pen/LYqwwEd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the flex property and replace the below code to set the title on the left side and the image on the right side.

```css
html {
    width: 279px;
    height: 127x;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

#body {
    width: 100%;
}

#main-header-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#main-header-1 {
    font-family: 'Mark Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 450;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    color: #000000;
}

#main-header-2 {
    font-family: 'Mark Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 450;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    color: #5D5D5D;
}

.icon_moreInfo {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: right;
}

img {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
}

.main-header-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-header-wrapper">
    <div id="main-header">
        <span id="main-header-1">Title</span> <span id="main-header-2">Subtitle</span>
    </div>
    <div id="icon_moreInfo">
        <img src="https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180718/brv/kisspng-computer-icons-icon-design-encapsulated-postscript-more-info-icon-5b4fcee4e70c74.9013090315319569649464.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks it works! 
another question the img is too near to the right edge, how can i add a space in between the img and right edge. I tried margin-right :5px on .icon_moreInfo , it doesnt work

Comment: Give margin-right: 5px to the image for the space between the image and the right edge.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example helps you:

```css
html {
      width: 279px;
      height: 127x;
      background: #EEEEEE;
    }

    #main-header {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 12px;
      float: left;
    }

    #main-header-1 {
      font-family: 'Mark Pro';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 450;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 100%;
      letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      color: #000000;
    }

    #main-header-2 {
      font-family: 'Mark Pro';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 450;
      font-size: 10px;
      line-height: 100%;
      letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      color: #5D5D5D;
    }

    #icon_moreInfo {
      float: left;
      margin-top: 12px;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    img {
      height: 12px;
      width: auto;
    }

    #main-header-wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main-header-wrapper">
    <div id="main-header">
      <span id="main-header-1">Title</span> <span id="main-header-2">Subtitle</span>
    </div>

    <div id="icon_moreInfo">
      <img
        src="https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180718/brv/kisspng-computer-icons-icon-design-encapsulated-postscript-more-info-icon-5b4fcee4e70c74.9013090315319569649464.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```